# Can hibernate enable "compress" option in oracle?

Tags: oracle, hibernate

Can Hibernate enable "compress" option in oracle or it can be done only by oracle itself? I want to create compressed tables automatically.

Comment: Sorry I doubt you really need it. There are at least three different compress options in Oracle. Most of them are extra cost options - i.e. you must pay additional license fees if you want to use them. The only one which is free of charge is so called "offline" compression.  This one works only when using bulk loads - but this most probably can not be done via hibernate. You really should talk to your local DBAs before using compression in Oracle.

Comment: @ibre5041 True, but i'm curious about the possibility.

Comment: as @ibre5041 points out you mean the **OLTP compression** available from Oracle 11g. Technically it is enbled with the DDL `ALTER TABLE  tst COMPRESS FOR ALL OPERATIONS`. This means that the connection used in Hibernate must have granted the *ALTER* privilege on the table. Also the database must have enabled the Advaced Compression option. Check  `select * from v$option where parameter = 'Advanced Compression' and value = 'TRUE';` Allthough most DBAs anticipates, that Hibernate can do unexpectable things, it is a good idea to consult you action with them....